# curl login script to visual c#

Tags: c#, http, curl, request

I have the working cURL script:
`curl --insecure --data 'username=xxxx&password=xxxx' --dump-header headers https://$ipAddress/login`

Trying to do the same thing on Visual C# but it does not work:

```
private void myExamplelogin(string ipAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            string user = xxxx;
            string pass = xxxx;
            string url = "https://" + ipAddress + "/login";

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, x509Certificate, chain, errors) => true;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url); 
            request.Method = "POST";             
            string postData = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData); 
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();  

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable". But when I try connect manually, the server is OK.

What seems to be wrong with code?

Comment: Use a sniffer and compare manual code with c# and see differences.  Usually it is due to missing headers.  then add missing headers to the c# code.

Comment: the cURL script is very simple. there is no way to have similar in .net than checking with a sniffer? which i do not have...

Comment: Download fiddler or wireshark for free.

Comment: could you sniff on https?

Comment: Yes.  The headers aren't encrypted.  http uses tcp as transport layer you will see multiple tcp for each http.  It will also use port forwarding so messages will show up on other port numbers.  Make sure you trace all IP messages between the two client/source IP addresses.